# Grabbing Kendo Spreadsheet & WYSIWYG Editor PDF Export dataURI

Tags: kendo-ui, editor, spreadsheet

Is there a way to grab the base64 dataURI from the pdf export for the Kendo Spreadsheet and WYSIWYG Editor widgets like there is for the Kendo Gantt widget?

I'm referencing this [Kendo UI Dojo Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/unuNo/4) as well as the Telerik forum question ["Get Base64 From Export PDF"](http://www.telerik.com/forums/get-base64-from-export-pdf)

The code looks like this for successfully obtaining the base64 data from the Gantt widget:

```
    $("#gantt").kendoGantt({
        toolbar: ["pdf"],
        dataSource: [
          {
            id: 1,
            orderId: 0,
            parentId: null,
            title: "Task1",
            start: new Date("2014/6/17 9:00"),
            end: new Date("2014/6/17 11:00")
          }
        ],
        pdfExport: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            gantt._drawPDF()
              .then(function(root) {
                  return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(root, {
                      // PDF options
                  });
              })
              .done(function(dataURI) {
                  console.log(dataURI);
                  // Data URI available here
              });
         }
      });
      var gantt = $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt");
```

You'll notice the dataURI can be accessed here `.done(function(dataURI){...})` in the pdfExport object.

**Is there something similar for both the [Spreadsheet](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet) and the [WYSIWYG Editor](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/index)?**  I've scoured the documents and forums but no dice.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with the following snippet from the editor API:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
        tools: ["pdf"],
        value: "sample editor data"
    }
});

var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");

editor._drawPDF()
    .then(function(root) {
        return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(root, {});
    })
    .then(function(dataURI) {
        console.log(dataURI);
});
```

Looks like we were able to pare down the code to the bare minimum and it functioned the way we needed it to. Here's a link to a working demo provided by Kendo: [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AyuZO)

Please note that the code uses internal methods that doesn't seem to be apart of their PublicAPI.

As for the Spreadsheet... they opened a feature request ticket for this feature.  We used their server-side API to generate the PDF information since there doesn't appear to be a way to grab the dataURI through the JavaScript API.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the exact same approach with the Kendo UI Editor, but not with the Spreadsheet.

Comment: If you don't mind, please provide more information, code, etc and how it would be done, if another way exists, to obtain the dataURI from the Spreadsheet widget.